# Error Number 1919 During index creation for image column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have made a lot of research on the best of storing image on sqlserver database.Many relevant links on stack overflow, Recommend either using FileStream and some recommend storing image with certain size.eg(Image size less than 2MB). eg:[this posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994130/whats-the-best-way-to-store-different-images-in-the-database)
    I decided the store my image on the database because my application validate all the image size to less than 1MB to be inserted. For better performance i want to index these image column but i have this error:  I keep getting sql error:1919
On Microsoft site,this means Cannot create index on a column of text, ntext, or image data type. 
    But my datatype is varbinary(Max)

here  is my table script:

```
USE [MobileDBU]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[storeimage]    Script Date: 01/17/2014 12:13:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[storeimage](
[Photo] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
[SSN] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Why do you need index your image content?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau,I have a view depend on the table.So i index it to gain fast search

Comment: What is gonna be your search criteria?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau, this table is posted is experimental,my production database store photo as image datatype and it allows null,But i have experience a bad performance long run queries.Now i want to enhance my  db design. one posibility i came across was that image stored as varbinary(Max) can be  index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your requirement right I would suggest to bring an additional field in your storage table. The field should act like an unique identifier of an image. for this purpose you can use auto identity, GUID, the image HashCode, the image file name, ... you name it.
Then you should use the "ID" constraint in dependent table.

something like that:

```
Table ImageStore(Id INT Primary KEY, ImageBlob [varbinary](max), ...)
Table ImageNotes (
   ImageId INT, 
   NoteId INT,
   Node Text, ...
   PRIMARY KEY ([ImageId], [NodeId]),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ImageNotes_ImageStore FOREIGN KEY ([ImageId]) REFERENCES [ImageStore]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
 )
```

Comment: @Yanugen Vlasau, your is a better approach and i have modified my design to reflect your solution,it work with little addiontion:On update cascade